# Will the license I am writing hold up?

Tags: united-states, software, licensing

I am writing a software license for my software that I wrote and I wondering if I could take someone to court if, for example, they shared the source code.
My goal is to have a license that you can share the software but not the source code.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bUxLck9Ay84-dMkzLLKioQrM2LWph-z6NjzWoc6KHGQ

Comment: At the moment this is very vague and the 'question' doesn't contain any actual information - add the text from your google doc to this question and include what your intended goal is to ensure this 'works'. Changing the title would be useful too - at the moment it doesn't tell anyone what the question is about.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it! Thank you @LioElbammalf

Comment: @LioElbammalf is this better?

Comment: Just reading the title and neither the body nor the actual license document - I'd spontaneously say "no"

Comment: "Any copies" means it'd be also breaking the license just to download the source code at all...

Comment: Voted to close. This is a request for legal advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a challenging license, because it is so unclear. If this were to go to court, the primary issue is likely to be "what exactly is allowed?". As I suppose you know, nobody can copy anything of yours unless you give them permission. I cannot figure out from this what acts you intend to permit. The courts will follow some interpretive procedure to figure this out, though the procedure will vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. In the US, the defendant might move for [summary dismissal](https://www.federalrulesofcivilprocedure.org/frcp/title-vii-judgment/rule-56-summary-judgment/) because their copying was authorized. As a matter of law, the license cannot be said to clearly and effectively allow only that which you seem to want to allow. Since the license is ungrammatical at a number of points, the courts would have to struggle to assign a reasonable interpretation: why should they favor you over the licensee in this enterprise? The courts are supposed to be neutral, and not favor the plaintiff.

Paragraph 2 is legally null: you can't copyright a name. You're writing a bare license, not a contract, so there is no "do X in exchange for Y" hook that allows you to restrict the use of a name. (However, you could independently cook up a trademark scheme that would allow you to control use of the particular trademark).